# saving states or proceeding form data when creating a VSTS extension

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to make a VSTS extension that works like this

[image]

The Personas extension lets the user type in the Name, Tag, Description, and Avatar, and add the item on the left column as shown in the image.

This wouldn't be a hard task if I do it on a web, but since this is my first time creating an extension for VSTS, I am not sure how to approach this.

I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/get-started/node?view=vsts

and successfully deployed my extension with just my name displayed.

Below is my code that displays some form.

**my_hub.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(0, 67, 117);
            color: white;
            margin: 10px;    
            font-family: "Segoe UI VSS (Regular)","-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        VSS.init();
        console.log(VSS);
        VSS.ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("name").innerText = VSS.getWebContext().user.name;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>        
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

This successfully displays the form in the extension, but my questions are:

1. How do we save the state so that we can display the saved form data on the left column as shown in the image?
2. How do we submit the form data to proceed? Do we need a database for this? If so, how do we set it up for this task?

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For developing vsts extension, we do not offer the ability to use a database.

You need to use **[Data storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts)**. VSTS extensions have the ability to store user preferences and complex data structures directly on Microsoft-provided infrastructure. This ensures your user's data is secure and backed up just like other account and project data. It also means for simple data storage needs, you (as the extension provider) are not required to setup or manage (or pay for) third-party data storage services.

> The service is designed to let you store and manage two different
>   types of data:
>
> - Settings: simple key-value settings (like user preferences)
> - Documents: collections of similar complex objects (documents)

More details about how to set storage please refer official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts#setting-storage).

Comment: I used the exact code from the tutorial. The `dataService.getValue` and `dataService.setValue` work. But what are the functions for removing it, or editing it?

Comment: I figured out that this is possible by using documents instead of key-value storage. My new question is, how can I display all data I have? I tried to use`getDocuments` to fetch all data I have, but it only works inside `VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then...` loop.

Comment: To rephrase my question, `dataService.getDocuments("MyCollection").then(function(docs)` I cannot store `docs`, which is the collection of my data in object format, into another variable. I need to store it in a different variable to re-use it to display in the HTML. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please disregard my question above since I figured it out. However, I have another issue. Can the document storage be shared with another extension? I tried to use `dataService.getDocuments("MyCollection2")` in a different extension, but it seems like they are not shared. Is this possible?

Comment: @Dawn17 No for now.